# Async function inside useEffect return undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, next.js, try-catch

I have an async function inside useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const res = await checkLogin();
      console.log(res);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

checkLogin returning "Hello world"

```
 async function checkLogin() {
  try {
  const resp = await linstance.get("/api/auth/user");

  setUser(resp.data.user);
  setEmail(resp.data.email);
  setId(resp.data.id);

  return "Hello world";
} catch (error) {
  return error.response;
}
```

}

why in the console.log it's print undefined?

I want checkLogin response to be "Hello world" (to make it clear)

Comment: post the `checkLogin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `checkLogin()` your code has `try/catch`. If try block run successfully, you would get "Hello world" in the console.

But most likely your code is falling into the `catch` block. it is throwing error and `error` object has no `response` property. In the `catch` block

```
 catch (error) {
  // check what is logging here
  console.log("error in fetchLogin", error)
  return error.response;
}
```